# Django вопрос по field в моделях

Tags: база-данных, django, orm

В чем практическая разница  между  TextField и  CharField ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть в том, что за ORM стоит база данных и поле в таблице БД зависит от того какое поле джанги ты используешь. Это text и varchar соответственно. В случае постгреса разницы нет никакой, с другими БД возможно иначе.

Совсем на практике же, в джанге CharField требует параметр максимальной длины, а TextField нет